# Remove a project / package / repository from RForge

Tags: r, r-forge

Since I have moved my R projects from `RForge` to `GitHub`, I desired to remove them from  the old hosting. However i didn't found the way, yet (in the admin pages, the manuals don't mention it).

Is that possible or a mail to the admins is the only way? (not a problem, but if there is an automatic way i would happily preserve their time/efforts).

Thanks, Luca

Comment: [that's what they state on the website](http://r-forge.wu-wien.ac.at/tracker/?func=detail&atid=194&aid=4784&group_id=34): email. That being said, I emailed them a few days ago, and no answer yet, so it might take a while.

Comment: @baptiste thanks for the links, quite a hidden url (a bug report!) :)

Comment: yep, my friend google presented it to me a few days ago

Comment: when i [searched](https://www.google.it/search?q=remove+packagerforge&oq=remove+packagerforge&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.7104j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=remove+package+rforge) i found only [this](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=283&group_id=34&atid=196)... but in the second page of results [it seems that it's possible](https://r-forge.wu-wien.ac.at/tracker/?func=detail&atid=194&aid=5219&group_id=34) also via a bug request